# GPS coordinates to neighboorhood?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I have tried both Google and Yahoo's Geocoding services to get the Montreal neighborhood/district from GPS coordinates but while they are both able retrieve the correct (address, city, state, country) they won't retrieve the neighborhood.

Which Geocoding service would offer this service? Otherwise, where can I find the neighborhood data to do it myself?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the reverse geocoder available though the Flickr API:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.places.findByLatLon.html

That will resolve to the neighbourhood level. There's also a reverse geocoding flag in the YQL/PlaceFinder API:

http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showtopic=7238

This may resolve to the neighbourhood, but be aware it often returns a zip code.

Comment: +Yahoo Geocoding Wrapper https://github.com/recoset/node-geocode - see example

Answer (score 3):

Geonames, Bing, and Google also provide geocoding services. With Bing and Google, if you type in the name of the neighborhood into their maps.google/maps.bing service and the result is successful, chances are their geocoding API will work.

You can also look for higher quality spatial data from Statistics Canada (http://www12.statcan.ca/census-recensement/2006/geo/index-eng.cfm).

Answer (score 2):

While this won't necessarily help you since you are in Canada, for those looking for neighborhood boundaries in the US, Zillow "[announced the release of shapefile data of boundaries for over 7,000 neighborhoods covering 150 cities in the United States](http://gislounge.com/zillow-releases-neighborhoods-in-shapefile-format/)" (1/18/08) under a Creative Commons license.

You can download the shapefiles state-by-state at their [website](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm).